# Submenu does not work

Tags: html, css

Having tried just about everything i can, i just can't get the sub menu to display, i have read articles about CSS and searched the net all day trying different ideas and nothing has worked up to now, i am wondering if it's my containers but i can't see it.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* Main CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#header-content {
  background: url('../images/header1.jpg') repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  height: 167px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/* Menu Start */

#bandmenu-content {
  padding-top: 134px;
  width: 100%;
}
#bandmenu-content ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#bandmenu-content li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1px;
}
#bandmenu-content a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
#bandmenu-content ul a:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
/* Sub Menus */

#bandmenu-content ul ul {
  display: none;
  background-color: #abc;
}
#bandmenu-content li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="bandmenu-content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="members.html">Members</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="song-list.html">Song List</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="shows.html">Shows</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="comments.html">Comments</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I just remembered setting the sub menu vertically is a problem as well.

Comment: The Members sub menu under About display fine for me.

Comment: For me works fine too

Comment: HEre's the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/F0BDJX1Mak7IqPFDPGSA It works fine here. the only thing that i remove is the **@charset "utf-8";** on the css

Comment: That is strange as i have tried it in Microsoft Expression web 4 and Dream Weaver 2015 and nothing!

Comment: Can you specify which browsers you've tested this in? Because it's working for me in Fiddle as well. I'm on Chrome.

Comment: Did you use `<doctype html>` ?